# Change a char to int* in push_back(); of vector<int>

Tags: c++, vector, char, int, push-back

I have this problem, I try to change a char to int, but nothing happens.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector<int> m,n;

    void my_f()
    {
        bool *quad; quad=new bool; *quad=false;
        if(*quad)
            {
                char *v; v=new char;
                bool *vv; vv=new bool; *vv=false;
                while(!*vv)
                {
                    cin >> *v;
                    if(*v>48 && *v<57)   
                    {*vv=true; m.push_back((int)*v); n.push_back((int)*v);}
                }
                delete v; delete vv;
            }
            else
            {
                char *v,*w; v=new char;w=new char;
                bool *vv; vv=new bool; *vv=false;
                while(!*vv)
                {
                    cin >> *v;cin >> *w; //input: 2 1
                    if(*v>48 && *v<57 && *w>48 && *w<57)
                    {*vv=true; m.push_back(*v); n.push_back(*w); cout <<"si";} 
                    cout << *v << *w << endl; // output: 2 1
                }
                delete v; delete w; delete vv;
            }
            cout << m[0]<<n[0]; // output: 50 49
    }
```

I try with this in iteration:

```
if(*v=='0' || *v=='1' || *v=='2' || *v=='3' || *v=='4' || *v=='5' || *v=='6' || *v=='7' || *v=='8' || *v=='9'
           || *w=='0' || *w=='1' || *w=='2' || *w=='3' || *w=='4' || *w=='5' || *w=='6' || *w=='7' || *w=='8' || *w=='9')
{...}
```

Also this in *push_back();* :

```
m.push_back(*v); n.push_back(*w);

m.push_back((int)*v); n.push_back((int)*w);

m.push_back(static_cast<int>(*v)); n.push_back(static_cast<int>(*w));
```

And I get the same output in *m[0]* and *n[0]*, the ACSII table values

This isn't duplicate because I prove all tips in this forum such as I show in down part

Comment: Gotta [MCVE] please?

Comment: See `isdigit`, it can save you a lot of effort.

Comment: Your program is missing the definition for `quad`, so I couldn't compile it.

Comment: Please be consistent with comparisons, sometimes you compare to 48, other places you use '0'.  I highly recommend using the character literals because not everybody has the ASCII chart memorized in decimal.

Comment: Also, the C++ language is not C# or Java; you don't need to use `new` to declare variables; try without using `new`.  Without `new`, the compiler can easily decide to place variables in registers which will speed up your program.

Comment: Already fix definition `quad`.
I already try with '0'...'9' values in iteration.
And try removing the `new` and the problem persist